# Remap Surface Type keyboard "special keys" to standard function keys

Tags: keyboard, microsoft-surface

The top row of the MS Surface Type keyboard mostly consists of special keys for increasing volume, searching, accessing settings, etc.  But if you hold the "Fn" key, then that row becomes the standard function keys (F1 - F12).  I'd like remap the keys so that without "Fn" pressed, it is the standard F# keys, and with the "Fn" press, it is the special key.  So basically flip what the key is for "Fn pressed" vs. "Fn not pressed".

What is the easiest way for me to accomplish this?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**Press Fn + Caps**

This will toggle the Fn key so that F-keys are the default.

You may need to install/update the "Trackpad Settings" app and install all your Windows Updates -- I think this keyboard shortcut may have came in a recent update.

Also, I beleive this fix currently only works with Surface Pro + Type Cover. Please post a comment if you can confirm it works on others combos (RT, Touch Cover)...

Enjoy! :D

Comment: Seems to work on the Touch Cover with Windows 8.1 Pro.

Comment: This (of course) also turn my two most used keys, PgUp and PgDown, into two of the most useless function keys, F11&F12. Any way to make it a bit more selective?

Comment: Also working with my 1st gen Surface Pro under Ubuntu 18.04, thank you for this answer.

Answer (score 2):

If you Press <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>Caps</kbd> keys the same time, you would be able to toggle the lock on the function keys.

Answer (score 0):

caps plus fn didn't work for me.  I ended up toggling them by finding the option on one of my laptop's BIOS menus. For an HP, I pressed F10 at bootup and went to configuration options.  From there, there was an "action keys" option that I disabled.  Maybe different for other machines.